# creating a list when calling a method

Tags: c#

I have a method with the following signature:

```
public void SomeMethod(int SomeInt, List<long> SomeListOfLongs)
```

At one point, I'm calling this method and the code looks somewhat like this:

```
int TheInt = 2;
long TheLong1 = 3;
long TheLong2 = 4;
```

I'd like to create the list of longs and call the method in one step. I tried this:

```
SomeMethod(TheInt, new List<long>(TheLong1, TheLong2));
```

Is there a way to avoid having to create a new list directly in the call itself?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the question is really "Can I create the list inline with the method call?"  which you have discovered that, yes you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You're going to create the new list. That shouldn't cause any issues though.

If you have control over the method, you could change the signature to:

```
public void SomeMethod(int someInt, params long[] someArrayOfLongs)
```

Then you'd be able to call the method with the following code:

```
SomeMethod(TheInt, TheLong1, TheLong2);
```

Comment: @frenchie - I updated the answer just in case you have the ability to change the method signature.

Comment: Ok, that's a workable solution but I'll just keep my code with the list created and then passed; just looks cleaner. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hey, look at what I came up with tinkering with the code a bit more! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just was tinkering with the code and figured out that it IS possible:

```
SomeMethod(TheInt, new List<long>() { TheLong1, TheLong2 });
```

Comment: You said "Is there a way to avoid having to create a new list directly in the call itself?" - what you did creates a list, so this isn't really an answer.

Comment: Your original question asks how to make the call without creating a new List. This also creates a new List. Not sure how it solves your problem.

Comment: Seems more likely that the question was stated wrong, not that this answer is wrong.

Comment: I should have stated differently: "how to call a method AND create a list in one line"?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        call(1, new List<long> { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    }
    void call(Int32 i,List<long> l)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((l[0] + l[1] + l[2] + l[3]).ToString());
    }



       i tried this and working properly so use this code too pass the List object.....
```